# Focus With Multiple Dialog Boxes (MFC)

Tags: mfc

I have a problem where clicking (anywhere) on a child dialog box within the application's main frame window causes a message box with NULL parent, which was visible, to be hidden behind the main window.

Say for example we have the following Z order (assuming zero is topmost):

MainWindow = 2, Dialog1 = 1, MessageBox = 0

When I click on Dialog1, it brings MainWindow in front of MessageBox , so we end up with:

MessageBox = 2, MainWindow=1, Dialog1 = 0

But these are both error messages (from different threads) and I don't want the user to acknowledge one then potentially ignore the other because it gets buried.

Some key points:

- Dialog1 is shown using DoModal() (not overidden) on receipt of a user defined message to MainWindow.
- MessageBox is shown from a separate thread. It's parent window is NULL. I can't set it's parent to MainWindow because the error can occur when MainWindow is waiting on a response from the function that triggered the error in the first place, which causes deadlock. This deadlock scenario isn't the case here as it happens, but I can't assume that from the thread that creates the message box.

I tried adding MB_APPLMODAL to the message box style but it didn't help. I don't want to make it topmost - that just irritates people.

Is there actually a way of preventing MainWindow jumping in front of this message box?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post message from the thread to Dialog1 so that Dialog1 can show MessageBox instead of the thread showing MessageBox.

If Dialog1 may/may not exist when MessageBox needs to be shown then you may have a mechanism where the message will be processed by MainWindow if Dialog1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I can do this (please correct me if I'm wrong). If the main window is already showing Dialog1 modally how will it respond to the message? It's perfectly valid for both error conditions to occur concurrently. Also, I need the return value from the message box in the other thread (it's a yes/no box), though I guess that could be worked around.

Comment: For this reason, I suggested to post message to Dialog1 and not main window. Dialog1 message can accept message from the thread if it is active. If you want return value from the message box then you can use SendMessage instead of PostMessage.

Comment: Hmm. I could consider that, but them I'm left needing to update some handle value every time a modal window is shown, which beside sounding horrible would be no small task - it's quite a big application. Having googled this a while I think I might be screwed on it :-(. If nobody else suggests anything more palatable soon I'll mark this as the answer for at least being an option. Thanks again.